# How to install Open NFC Simulator for Android?

Tags: android, emulation, nfc, nfc-p2p, open-nfc

I'm following [these instructions](http://open-nfc.org/wp/editions/android/#compilation) to install and use Open NFC Simulator for Android. I can't find the Open NFC image they talk about in step 2. Any advice?

Comment: Running the simulator (if you manage to set it up for 2 devices) is no comparison to the real experience. Furthermore, with the new hand-over feature to Bluetooth in JB 4.1 I suspect that this cannot be simulated at all.

Comment: Can you help me with the edited question? I'm trying to install Open NFC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, contacted the developers and they told me that the latest release (4.4.2) didn't include the compiled source code. So I used an [older version (4.4.1)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-nfc/files/Open%20NFC%204.4.1%20%2813312%29/Open%20NFC%20SDK%20for%20Android%20v4.4.1%20%2813751%29.zip/download), which included instructions in the directory Open NFC SDK for Android v4.4.1 (13751)\android_sdk\OpenNFC_AddOn\MAN_NFC_1204-314 Open NFC - Android ICS 4.0.3 - SDK v0.1

Answer (score 1):

You can [download it](http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-nfc/files/Open%20NFC%204.4.1%20%2813312%29/Open%20NFC%20SDK%20for%20Android%20v4.4.1%20%2813751%29.zip/download) from this link and extract addon_open_nfc_4.4.1_android_4.0.3 folder. and add it to your add-on folder.

Comment: After this step how to create an AVD with NFC enabled?